# How to make text animation on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I want to know how to make this simple effect to work on IE ? With Firefox and Google chrome working OK but IE is disaster :( I know it is probably most stupid question ever but i cant figure out how to do it

Thank you in advance!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Me</title>
 <style>
  body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
 }
.text-container h1 {
  font-size: 8vw;
  color: rgba(225,225,225,.1);
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496024840928-4c417adf211d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94616ccf14e7ed3eb6fe9afeb953aec3&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: animate 25s linear infinite;
 }
@keyframes animate {
   from {
    background-position: 0 0;
   }
   to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
   }
  }
.text-container {
  margin-top: 17%;
  text-align: center;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="text-container">
  <h1>HowTo Make It With IE?</h1>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE what? 8/9/10/11?

Comment: we are in 2018, you know that ? ---> http://caniuse.com